# Replace certain string with variable that using that string as variable name (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have some variables that was created dynamically. All of the variables using double underscores ('__') as a prefix. So What I want to do is replace any characters in a sentence that contain double underscores prefix with the variables. Here is an example:

**input**

```
var __total = 8;
var sentence = "There are __total planets in the solar system";
```

**expected result**

> There are 8 planets in the solar system

Here is my regex to parse the string, but it return undefined:

```
sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs,window['__' + "$1"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `window['__' + "$1"]` is evaluated first, so:

```
sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs,window['__' + "$1"]);
```

...becomes:

```
sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs, window['__$1']);
```

As `window['__$1']` doesn't exist on the window object, this results in `undefined`, so you get:

```
sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs, undefined);
```

This is what causes you to get `undefined` in your result. Instead, you can use the replacement function of `.replace()` to grab the group from the second argument and then use it for the replacement value returned by the callback:

```js
var __total = 8;
var sentence = "There are __total planets in the solar system";

const res = sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs, (_, g) => window['__' + g]);
console.log(res);
```

However, accessing global variables on the window like this isn't the best idea as this won't work for local variables or variables declared with `let` or `const`. I suggest you create your own object which you can then access like so:

```js
const obj = {
  __total: 8,
};

const sentence = "There are __total planets in the solar system";
const res = sentence.replace(/__(\w+)/gs, (_, g) => obj['__' + g]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` here an example:

```
let __total = 8;

let str = "There are __total planets in the solar system ";
let regex = /__(\w+)/g;
let variables = str.match(regex);
console.log(`There are ${eval(variables[0])} planets in the solar system`)
```

```js
let __total = 8;

let str = "There are __total planets in the solar system ";
let regex = /__(\w+)/g;
let variables = str.match(regex);

console.log(`There are ${eval(variables[0])} planets in the solar system`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to split the sentence and use the varialbe to get the value assigned to that.

So you have to use **'+'** sign for spliting and adding to the sentence

So you just find that word using regex.
Suppose you store it in the variable called **myVar**.
Then you can use the following code:
sentence.replace(myVar,'+ myVar +');

So your end goal to be to make your sentence like:

```
sentence = "There are "+__total+" planets in the solar system";
```